# dataGridView default error dialog handle

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to hide default datagridview error dialog.
I put in the code this event handler:

```
        this.dataGridView2.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(dataGridView2_DataError);


    private void dataGridView2_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //empty so it doesn't show anything
    }
```

But still when i try this and leave datagridview cell empty ( delete everything from it), it show me dialog box with error.

Screenshot of error:

[image]

Comment: Can we assume that you get your names right and have indeed hooked up one event to both DGVs?

Comment: @TaW Oh I missed it, and banging my head why it isn't hiding the dialog..

Comment: Oh i get it now. I hooked event on dgv1 and was testing it on dgv2. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to Handle and `Cancel` the event:

```
private void dataGridView2_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Also, subscribe to the event in `InitializeComponent()`

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   //...
   this.dataGridView.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.dataGridView2_DataError);
}
```

Comment: Still the same. DataGridView default dialog still shows.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: @DoLoop How many GridView do you have? Are you subscribing all of them to this event?

Comment: In that form 2, 1 i am using and 1 for test (datagridview2)

Comment: You have to subscribe both to this event. Have you?

Comment: Thanks. I managed to solve it. Cancel event is working. Thanks

Comment: I hooked event on dgv1 and was testing it on dgv2. but now i corrected it and it is working

Comment: @Niraj Please read the conversation above. It may help you. If not, ask another question with all the details.

Comment: This solved my problem, there is just one thing; my pop-up window keeps opening multiple times like it is spamming me for some reason. This prevents the problem but it is not popping out just once, not 3-5, a lot.

Comment: Its Works , I was facing problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code to handle the event:

```
private void dataGridView2_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code , it's work!

```
 private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //To handle 'ConstraintException' default error dialog (for example, unique value)
            if ((e.Exception) is System.Data.ConstraintException)
            {
                // ErrorText glyphs show
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "must be unique value";
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "must be unique value";

                //...or MessageBox show
                MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Error ConstraintException",
                                               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                //Suppress a ConstraintException
                e.ThrowException = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR: dataGridView1_DataError",
                                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }         
    }
```