# Catching exceptions from list of objects bound to DataGridView

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview, presentation-layer

I am working on a project where the concerns are divided into 3 layers (Presentation, Business Logic and Data Access). Using exception bubbling, I am able to pass exceptions from one layer to another until I can finally catch it and display a message from the Presentation Layer. However, I have no clue how to do this whenever a cell is updated in the datagridview.

```
//Business entity:
class Clients : Person
{
    public override string FirstName
    {
        set
        {
            try
            {
                fc.lettersOnlyUpcaseFirstChar(ref value, false);
                dal.update(this.GetType().Name, "FirstName", value, "ClientID", clientID.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        } 
    }
}

//Format checking helper class:
class formatChecks
{
    public void lettersOnlyUpcaseFirstChar(ref string input, bool nullable)
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");
        if (input == "" && !nullable)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value can not be null.");
        if (!input.All(Char.IsLetter))
            throw new FormatException("Value may only contain letters (a-z, A-Z).");
        char[] letters = input.ToLower().ToCharArray();
        letters[0] = char.ToUpper(letters[0]);
        string outs = new string(letters);
    }
}

//Business layer helper class:
class BLHandler
{
    // initialize list of Clients by using a Data Access class...
    ArrClients = dal.selectAll("Clients", typeof(Clients).AssemblyQualifiedName).Cast<Clients>().ToList();
}

//The list bound to a datagridview in the presentation layer:
public frmMain()
{
    dgvCustomers.DataSource = BHandler.ArrClients;
}
```

I know I could do the format checking in the presentation layer, but I would prefer to do it this way. Is there any way I can make this work?

Comment: Where is that property being set? If your try wraps the piece of code that sets the value you should be fine.

Comment: Whenever I update the value in the DataGridView, it automatically handles updating the bound object for me. So I don't use any code to set the value.

Comment: Maybe try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37776914/11350283 , you'll probably have to handle the exceptions in the DataGridView by handling the event

Comment: Since you are using the 3-Tier Architecture, which is nice and good. I believe your presentation should deal with the BLL (only) which deals with the DAL to get the required data or the thrown exceptions. Let the BLL catches the exceptions and pass them to the front end to do something about them.